# Using JSON Query with Nagios API

Tags: javascript, json, cors, nagios

I am developing a dashboard for Nagios and I would like to use the JSON Query generator Nagios provides to get the data.

Here is my JavaScript :

```
    window.onload = function(){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET","http://localhost/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=host&hostname=belge",true);
    Httpreq.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("nagiosadmin:nagiosadmin"));
    Httpreq.send(null);
    var object = Httpreq.responseText;
    console.log(object); 
    button.textContent = "Yay";
    console.log("Success"); 
};
```

I am getting this error with Chrome debug console :

> index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=host&hostname=belge. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

I know it's related to Access Control Origin policy, so I add this header to my Apache server :

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

I use Postman to check my request is working, and it is, even if Postman has no Access Control Origin policy, I can check that the following header is present on the response :

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *

I tried a lot of things, but I can't get rid of this error.

Thanks for your time

Comment: did you check this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com

Comment: Solution: configure the `http://localhost` server to not require authentication for OPTIONS requests. Why: Your browser is doing a CORS preflight, which means that the browser is on its own automatically sending an OPTIONS request to `http://localhost/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi` before sending your GET request. And the server is apparently requiring authentication for OPTIONS requests, as it does  for GET requests; the server is expecting to see an Authorization header in that OPTIONS request. But the server shouldn’t be, because the browser doesn’t send that header when it does the OPTIONS

Comment: @sideshowbarker
I tried to disable server authentication for OPTIONS by adding the following header in my apache2.conf file :
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-controler-Allow-Headers "accept,content-type"`
but I still have the same error . What have I done wrong ?

I am currently trying to do it with a php script and it seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure the CORS policy on my Apache 2 server using Nagios, here are the lines I had to add:

- In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

  ```
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "\*"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200]
  ```
- In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nagios.conf`: I replaced the line `Require valid-user` with:

  ```xml
  <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
  ```